# PHP - If a field has a certain text value then print something

Tags: nodes, theming

The following PHP in a node tpl file:

```
check_plain($node->field_room[$node->language][0]['value'])
```

Will print this in the page:
Value1

What I want however is if the field has a value of 'Value1' then I want to print something else on the page. Ive tried the following but I think I have a syntax error:

```
if ( check_plain($node->field_room[$node->language][0]['value']) == "Value1" ) {
                        echo "<p>Print something else </p>";
                    }
```

Comment: You should not need the check_plain() call for this purpose, by the way. I don't think it's the cause of the problem, though, unless the value you are actually checking for has HTML special characters in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no syntax error in the second code sample, if you're getting a syntax error it's not coming from those lines.

The best way to get values from an entity is with [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7):

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_room');
if (count($items) && check_plain($items[0]['value']) == 'Value1') {
  // Do something
}
```

But unless you have some sort of multi-lingual issue the code you've got should do exactly the same thing as that, so the problem might be elsewhere.